# Ran install from ISO to disk(Trial)Ubuntu 14.04, the disk installed beside windows10 but now have 2 screens to load...

Tags: boot, dual-boot, live-cd

Turn on power, screen asks which to load(From windows) So, I select windows, and poof, good !   Then if I choose Ubuntu, a screen says stuff, and ESCape is my option.  Then I choose to boot (f9) Ubuntu, and another Ubuntu screen appears.

I got a pastebin, 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/14673246/

I'm worried wubi will destroy the computer... and, I would like to just click on ONE or the other to load whichever OS I need to use...instead of having the two loaders... as I do now.  Whatever did this was from the live-install icon for 14.04, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixing grub menu after migrating wubi to partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/264344/fixing-grub-menu-after-migrating-wubi-to-partition)

Comment: Read that question and it's answer.  That may help you.

Comment: Reading, but i am afraid to .. mess with this.  A broken Wubi has been detected. Please fix it this way:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Cannot_boot_into_Ubuntu

Comment: It looks like you have an EFI install of Windows.  You can't use wubi with EFI to my knowledge.

Comment: Uninstalled Wubi / Ubuntu.  Re-installed via liveCD option says "Install Ubuntu" (Not try it.)  Ubuntu is definitely working from the firmware... But, Windows boot mgr has no entry to load it, so I have to exit windows via troubleshooting/firmware advanced settings, or hold shift/on restart to load Ubuntu.

Comment: Read "http://askubuntu.com/questions/264344/fixing-grub-menu-after-migrating-wubi-to-partition?lq=1"  and Got very interested !  Still not sure what to do about getting Ubuntu into that boot file.

Comment: Hold on a minute

Comment: Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so now your problem seems to be that there is no boot menu entry.

Use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to set this up.  [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/140376/366676) has a more detailed description.

This will let you select wether to boot into Windows or Ubuntu from the windows boot menu.

If you don't like booting to GRUB after you select Ubuntu, you can configure GRUB to have a 0 second delay, so that you don't see it.  It will remain hidden.

Comment: And I have confirmed myself that this **DOES** work in Windows 10 (at least it does in the Enterprise version).

Comment: Have Home version. HP i5 4core.  I also read this...  "" Alternatively you can use "Dual-boot Repair Tool" which has a graphical interface to bcdboot.exe, bootsect.exe and other useful functions like boot sector view and one click dual-boot repair function for Windows 10/8/7/Vista  (also can fix Windows XP boot files).

Comment: EasyBCD will do that for you, and it's very simple and easy to do.  I strongly suspect that this will work with Home, since they use the exact same bootloader.